# How can I combine two arrays in into one single array?

Tags: php, arrays, arraylist, codeigniter-3

I am having to add more functionality in my codeigniter project. Here is the [jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/touqeershafi/t7t6gzve). I have an array like this:

```
$faculty = array(2, 3, 4);
```

and

```
$message = array('test1', 'test2', 'test3');
```

I'm also having an last insert id from another database:

```
$last_inserted_id = 1;
```

I want to combine the data to form an array like this:

```
$array = array(array('faculty' => 2, 'message' => 'test1', 'id' => 1),
               array('faculty' => 3, 'message' => 'test2', 'id' => 1), 
               array('faculty' => 4, 'message' => 'test3', 'id' => 1));
```

Thanks for everyone for your suggestions and time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this will you:

```
$array = [];
$faculty = array(2, 3, 4);
$message = array('test1', 'test2', 'test3');
$id = 1;
for ($key = 0; $key < count($faculty); $key++) {
    $array[$key]['faculty'] = $faculty[$key];
    $array[$key]['message'] = $message[$key];
    $array[$key]['id'] = $id;
}
print_r($array);
```

Comment: @Omi.Thanks its working. can please please explain how the code works

Comment: for will iterate till length of faculty or message array. Then fetching the value one by one from both array  $faculty[$key],$message[$key] it ll gives you the single value at $key position and assigning it to new array with keys that you want i.e faculty and message and same for id